# Automatic NiMH battery charger circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, batteries, battery-charging, nimh

[image]

I found this circuit on the web and I'm trying to charge a 1.2 V Ni-MH battery. The problem is that the circuit outputs 2.5 V (no load).

- Which elements should I change in this circuit?
- What is the role of the push button S1?
- Which elements play the role of protection?

Comment: The 2.5 V no-load output voltage is not necessarily a problem; it could well be a voltage-limited current source for charging you are looking at (I haven't checked). Also, it says "batteries" at the output of the circuit. How many batteries is it supposed to charge simultaneously?

Comment: only one battery

Comment: With two batteries shown and the dashed line between them suggests a series string of even more in series and 12 V input, I would say the schematic is made for charging several batteries in series.

Comment: in case of only one battery what changes should I apply?